# Slidershow jquery and convert to css

Tags: jquery, css, html, seo, slider

I downloaded script for slider show and it work without problems but after implemented this slide show i have problems with seo optimalization in HTML5. Because this code using this `<div u="">` or `<img u="">` and its still write me that i cant use this combination div with tag "u".

**This is full script for slideshow:**

```
<!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
        <!-- To move inline styles to css file/block, please specify a class name for each element. --> 
        <!-- ================================================== -->
        <div id="slider1_container" style="display: none; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;
        top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
            <!-- Loading Screen -->
            <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Slides Container -->
            <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
                <div>
                    <img u="image" src2="../img/1920/red.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img u="image" src2="../img/1920/purple.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img u="image" src2="../img/1920/blue.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--#region Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
            <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-bullet-navigator-jquery.html -->
            <style>
                /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 21 css */
                /*
                .jssorb21 div           (normal)
                .jssorb21 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
                .jssorb21 .av           (active)
                .jssorb21 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
                .jssorb21 .dn           (mousedown)
                */
                .jssorb21 {
                    position: absolute;
                }
                .jssorb21 div, .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av {
                    position: absolute;
                    /* size of bullet elment */
                    width: 19px;
                    height: 19px;
                    text-align: center;
                    line-height: 19px;
                    color: white;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    background: url(../img/b21.png) no-repeat;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
                .jssorb21 div { background-position: -5px -5px; }
                .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -5px; }
                .jssorb21 .av { background-position: -65px -5px; }
                .jssorb21 .dn, .jssorb21 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -5px; }
            </style>
            <!-- bullet navigator container -->
            <div u="navigator" class="jssorb21" style="bottom: 26px; right: 6px;">
                <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
                <div u="prototype"></div>
            </div>
            <!--#endregion Bullet Navigator Skin End -->

            <!--#region Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
            <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-jquery.html -->
            <style>
                /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 21 css */
                /*
                .jssora21l                  (normal)
                .jssora21r                  (normal)
                .jssora21l:hover            (normal mouseover)
                .jssora21r:hover            (normal mouseover)
                .jssora21l.jssora21ldn      (mousedown)
                .jssora21r.jssora21rdn      (mousedown)
                */
                .jssora21l, .jssora21r {
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
                    /* size of arrow element */
                    width: 55px;
                    height: 55px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    background: url(../img/a21.png) center center no-repeat;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
                .jssora21l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
                .jssora21r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
                .jssora21l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
                .jssora21r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
                .jssora21l.jssora21ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
                .jssora21r.jssora21rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }
            </style>
            <!-- Arrow Left -->
            <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora21l" style="top: 123px; left: 8px;">
            </span>
            <!-- Arrow Right -->
            <span u="arrowright" class="jssora21r" style="top: 123px; right: 8px;">
            </span>
            <!--#endregion Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
            <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Bootstrap Slider</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
```

I tried convert style from this code to css but after that slider dont work. Because i deleted all tag "u" and i used that only "class" for style. But after it dont work.

**This is css file where i try convert style from html to css but it dont work only this:**

```
#slider1_container { 
    display: none; 
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 1300px; 
    height: 580px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.slider_background {
    background-position: center top;
    background-color: black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 580px;
}

.loading {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;
}

#slider_filter {
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); 
    opacity: 0.7; 
    position: absolute; 
    display: block;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}

.slides {
    cursor: move; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 580px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.jssorb21 div, .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av {
    position: absolute;
    /* size of bullet elment */
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 19px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: url(../img/b21.png) no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.jssorb21 div { background-position: -5px -5px; }
.jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -5px; }
.jssorb21 .av { background-position: -65px -5px; }
.jssorb21 .dn, .jssorb21 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -5px; }

.jssora21l, .jssora21r {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /* size of arrow element */
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../img/a21.png) center center no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.jssora21l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
.jssora21r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
.jssora21l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
.jssora21r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
.jssora21l.jssora21ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
.jssora21r.jssora21rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }

#slider_image {
    position: absolute; 
    display: block; 
    background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my website where i stil trying implemented this without html errors for seo optimalization.

**OUTPUT ERRORS**

[VALIDATE WEB](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://rad3k.eu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use class name instead of id to define css.

```
.slider1_container {
    ...
}
```

To pass html validation please replace `u` attribute with `data-u`.

reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/pass-html-validation.html

Comment: Note that dimensions should always be specified in pixel. Please replace `width: 100%` with `width: 1300px;` for `.slides`.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Its amazing work, so thx :) and now i fixed all problem with style and now i trying fixed problem if i out zoom web to 4K resolution so slider jump from center to left, can you help me how can i fix it this. My website: http://rad3k.eu

Comment: I think it's not a problem of jssor slider. please check css of its parent container.